# Inserting database table data into array

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to insert the data in array so I can access specific values and display them. I am a newbie to java and I would like the answer to be simple.

```
try {
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
    ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmt = results.getMetaData();
    int numberOfColumns = rsmt.getColumnCount();

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
        System.out.print(rsmt.getColumnLabel(i) + "\t\t\t");
    }

    System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    while (results.next()) {
        int s_no = results.getInt(1);
        String s_name = results.getString(2);
        String s_surname = results.getString(3);

        System.out.println(s_no + "\t\t\t" + s_name + "\t\t\t" + s_surname);
    }

    results.close();
    stmt.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Records were not returned", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that usually, the better your question is, the more likely is it to get a valuable answer. This requires to write a good question. Maybe you consider to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get an idea of how to improve your question. Since code is involved you might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as well so that the code you post is most helpful.

Comment: You post code but do not state your problem. You want to insert data. Aha. Into the database or into the array? I guess into the array since you use SELECT instead of INSERT. You have some code which might or might not work. Does it? What do you expect? What does it do? Knowing this would make it easy to spot a problem. Easier than to identify the problem first and then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

storing resultset data in array is not possible.

better to create pojo class Student

```
public class Student {
     private int s_no;
     private String s_name;
     private String s_surname;

    public int getS_no() {
        return s_no;
    }
    public void setS_no(int s_no) {
        this.s_no = s_no;
    }
    public String getS_name() {
        return s_name;
    }
    public void setS_name(String s_name) {
        this.s_name = s_name;
    }
    public String getS_surname() {
        return s_surname;
    }
    public void setS_surname(String s_surname) {
        this.s_surname = s_surname;
    }

}
```

Storing logic :-

```
ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    List<Student> studs = new ArrayList<Student>();
    while (results.next()){

            Student stud = new Student();
            stud.setS_no(results.getInt(1));
            stud.setS_name(results.getString(2));
            stud.setS_surname(results.getString(3));
            studs.add(stud);
       }
```

all students have been added in list. Please iterate this list to fetch student data.

hope this will work for you